# Shiny DT Pre-select a column

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a shiny app which has two `DT` tables. In table `x1`, we select a row, i.e., if we select row 2 in `x1`, the data in `x2` is changing according to this selection. Then we select a column, i.e., column 3 in `x2`.

Now we change the selected row in `x1`. As a result, the data in `x2` will be updated and column selection is erased. I want the column selection to stay.

Sample data is created using iris dataset.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(caroline)
mydata <- groupBy(df=iris, by='Species', clmns=c('Sepal.Length','Sepal.Width','Petal.Length','Petal.Width'), aggregation='mean', full.names=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)
mydata2 <- iris
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      DT::dataTableOutput('x1')
    ),
    fluidRow(
      DT::dataTableOutput('x2')
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive({
         if(is.null(input$x1_rows_selected)){
            ind.x1 <- which(mydata2$Species== "setosa")
         }else{
            ind.x1 <- which(mydata2$Species== row.names(mydata)[input$x1_rows_selected])
         }
         return(mydata2[ind.x1, ])
    })

    output$x1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        mydata 
    }, selection = list(mode = 'single', target = 'row'))

    output$x2 = DT::renderDataTable({
      data()
    }, selection = list(mode = 'single', target = 'column'))
  }
)
```

Comment: Could you please generate some sample data for this? People might answer this with some sample `R` dataset like the `mtcars` or the `iris`. If you're data has some special characteristics this might not be what you are looking for

Comment: A sample data is added

Comment: This sample is fully functional. Therefore, you can test the app only this code. Now tell me how the selected column is x2 can be pre-selected?

Comment: I don't see how you can pre-select a column in `x2`. Since the content of `x2` is `reactive`, there is no way the selection you make will stay. You can only go the other way and do the selection over a drop down instead. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736201/keep-selected-rows-when-changing-dataset-in-shiny-dt-datatable), but likely due to the aforementioned reasons it doesnt work